# Log Into a Website with VBA and Selenium WebDriver

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I'm using a VBA macro in Excel 2016 along with Chrome and Selenium WebDriver to log-in to a website.  With VBA and IE I found a way to log in using the old SendKeys method

```
' Open the "AARP" web page
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "https://www.medicare.uhc.com/AARP"
    .Top = 0
    .Left = 0
    .Height = 1056
    .Width = 1936
End With
' Loop until the page is fully loaded
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4 And Not IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))

' Click the "Sign In" button
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary btn-block")(0).Click

' Loop until the page is fully loaded
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4 And Not IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:12"))

Set WSS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
my_PW = "123"
my_ID = "abc"

IE.Document.getElementById("EMAIL").Focus
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
WSS.SendKeys my_ID
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

IE.Document.getElementById("PASSWORD").Focus
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
WSS.SendKeys my_PW
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

IE.Document.getElementById("submitBtn").Click
```

Using more traditional code such as

```
IE.Document.getElementById("EMAIL").Value = "abc"
IE.Document.getElementById("PASSWORD").Value = "123"
```

failed.  **You need to physically interact with the textbox.**

I'm trying to migrate the code to work with Chrome and Selenium WebDriver.  When I use code such as

```
WDriver.FindElementById("EMAIL").SendKeys ("")     ' focus
WDriver.FindElementById("EMAIL").SendKeys ("abc")

WDriver.FindElementById("PASSWORD").SendKeys ("")  ' focus
WDriver.FindElementById("PASSWORD").SendKeys ("123")
```

it puts the text in the proper boxes, but when I click the "Submit" button the website doesn't log me in. I presume that the code fails because it is not physically interacting with the text boxes.  **How can I physically interact with the text boxes (like the old SendKeys method did with IE) using Selenium WebDriver in VBA?**

Thanks for your help...Ron

Answer (score 0):

With ie you need to trigger the change event listeners associated with those input fields. I can't test with selenium vba but I had no problem with Python selenium provided I added a wait condition.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Login()
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate2 "https://www.medicare.uhc.com/AARP"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector(".btn-primary").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        
        Dim t As Date, ele As Object
        t = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = .document.querySelector("#EMAIL")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t = 10 Then Exit Do       '<==To avoid infinite loop
        Loop While ele Is Nothing
        
        Dim evt As Object
        Set evt = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
        evt.initEvent "change", True, False
        
        If Not ele Is Nothing Then
        
            With .document.querySelector("#EMAIL")
                .Value = "abc"
                .dispatchEvent evt
            End With
            
            With .document.querySelector("#PASSWORD")
                .Value = "abc"
                .dispatchEvent evt
            End With
            
            .document.querySelector("#submitBtn").Click
        
        End If
        
        Stop

        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

---

Python selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.medicare.uhc.com/AARP'
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
d.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn-primary').click()
WebDriverWait(d,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "EMAIL"))).send_keys('abc')
d.find_element_by_id('PASSWORD').send_keys('abc')
d.find_element_by_id('submitBtn').click()
```

Comment: That's basically what I've tried in VBA, and although it places the desired text in the textbox, the website does not "see" it.  Is there a method like the old IE "SendKeys" that makes the website think you are actually typing in the text?

Comment: you have sendkeys in selenium basic you just add .sendkeys "text" to the end of the target element(s) . Did you try running my ie code as that works.

Comment: Yes, but the Selenium.sendkeys doesn't make the webpage think that the text was manually entered like the "old" SendKeys does, and is therefore not recognized.  Your IE code works fine, but my IE code (posted above) using SendKeys works too. Is your "querySelector" approach adaptable to Selenium VBA?

Comment: I don't think with selenium you need to add then trigger events. In my experience it has always triggered the existing event  listeners both in vba and other languages.  I may need to see if I can get selenium basic to work again though I gave up on it with windows 10 as never working for me.

Comment: You could try _WDriver.ExecuteScript "const changeEvent = new Event('change');arguments[0].dispatchEvent(changeEvent);", WDriver.FindElementById("EMAIL")_

Comment: That didn't work either.  No matter the code approach, A message always appears "Flash plug-in blocked on this page". Could that be a factor?

Comment: Really? I know my IE works to enter and submit the details as I tested it.

Comment: So "Flash plug-in blocked on this page". is not a factor I would suggest

Comment: With selenium basic you say it doesn't log you in. What happens? Do you get any kind of message from the page?

Comment: I can see my UName and PW in the correct textboxes, but when the Submit btn is clicked I get "Error: The username and password combination entered does not match our records."  I know the the UName and PW are correct.

Comment: Ah.... then perhaps my answer is also wrong as I used dummy login details. Have you checked to see what other event listeners and html changes occur when manually performing this?